# Run sequelize model hooks when seeding

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm currently trying to seed a postgresql database with sequelize, I have hooks declared on my model that work just fine when creating separate records (e.g. tests)

Does the data in my seed file need to be as how would show in the final table or can I call the hooks when creating?

Here are my files:

```
/*users-seed.js*/
'use strict'

module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [/*users-data*/])
  },
  down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.bulkDelete('Users', null, {})
  }
}
```

And

```
/*user.js*/
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  let User = sequelize.define('User', {
    /* user attributes */
  }, {
      instanceMethods: {
        hashPassword: function (password) {
          return bcrypt.hash(password, 15)
        },
        hashEmail: function (email) {
          return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(email).digest('hex')
        }
      },
      hooks: {
        beforeCreate: function (user) {
          return user.hashPassword(user.password_digest).then(function (hashedPassword) {
            user.email = user.hashEmail(user.email)
            user.password_digest = hashedPassword
          }).catch(e => { console.log('e', e); throw new Error(e) })
        },
        beforeBulkCreate: function (users) {
          return users.forEach(function (user) {
           return user.hashPassword(user.password_digest).then(function (hashedPassword) {
              user.email = user.hashEmail(user.email)
              user.password_digest = hashedPassword
            }).catch(e => { console.log('e', e); throw new Error(e) })
         })
        }
      }
    })
  return User
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so it was a mistake of mine, I missunderstood how `queryInterface.bulkInsert()` works, I thought it called the model hooks before "insert" (yes, this is what I missunderstood) them in the database, it inserts the raw data you put in the string, I think that is why in the docs the hooks are showed with a model instance using bulkCreate, bulkUpdate, etc